# Error During Importing Eclipse Project to Netbeans

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, netbeans, import

I implemented my project via Eclipse. However at the last minute, i realize that my code must be able to run in Netbeans Java SE 8 (JDK 8)

Below is the error faced when I tried to import. It is my first time during an import for Eclipse to Netbeans.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: it looks like you need to set your JDK to 1.8+ instead of the current 1.5 currently being used by your Eclipse

Comment: You are trying to compile the project with an old version of Java (namely something before java8 where lambdas were first introduced). In that case you obviously can not use lambdas. Update your Netbeans to compile with java8 or newer and you are fine.

Comment: Does that mean that my Netbeans version is too old to support lamdas? So i will only require to upgrade my Netbeans?

Comment: Your netbeans is 8, it supports lamda expressions.. Try Set your project to JDK 8 via right click properties.

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz "1.8+" is not quite correct. The only option in this case is "1.8" since NetBeans 8.2 does not support JDK 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correctly setting your Java Platform to JDK 8. The problem is that your **Source/Binary Format** setting is probably incorrect, and set to 1.5.

To fix that select your project's node in the **Projects** panel, right-click and select **Properties** from the popup menu, then click the **Sources** category. At the bottom of the screen set the **Source/Binary Format** to 1.8:

[image: NbSourceSetting]

(Updated to provide a screen shot for version 8.2 of NetBeans)